# FileUpload not working in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to upload a file in django.

It allows me to add the file in the form and submits with no errors but nothing gets stored. I am using django-crispy-forms

models.py

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='.')
```

views.py

```
class UploadsView(UpdateView):
    form_class = UploadForm
    template_name = 'upload.html'
    model = Upload
```

forms.py

```
class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UploadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Upload
        fields = ('upload',)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

form.html

```
<form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
             <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
             <a href="/home"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button></a>
</form>
```

Comment: try to specify the exact Media root like /home/User/project/static/media

Comment: Can you post your template html where the form is being rendered?

Comment: I have just used the `{{ form|crispy }}` tag in my form

Comment: changing the media root didn't work

Comment: Yes, but it's the outer <form> tag I'm interested in.

Comment: sorry. added into the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your form tag:

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads):

> Note that `request.FILES` will only contain data if the request method was `POST` and the `<form>` that posted the request has the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Otherwise, `request.FILES` will be empty.

Comment: perfect thank you. Don't know how i missed that from the docs

Comment: The only reason I could help was that I literally just fixed the same issue on a project I am working on.